# Multiple IF statements being true causes problems

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm having problems when multiple IF statements conditions are true.

My scenario, for example:

```
           if (B > A && B >= C && B > D && B> E )
           {
              while (h < B + 2)
              {
                 r.up();
                 h++;
              }
           }

           else if (D > A && D > B && D >= C && D > E )
           {
              while (h < D + 3)
              {
                 r.up();
                 h++;
              }
           }
           else if (C > A && C > B && C > D && C >= E )
           {
              while (h < C + 3)
              {
                 r.up();
                 h++;
              }
           }
```

This is just a template of my actual code, just so it looks a little more readable.

There's obviously more to the code since there's also A and E but I've only take part of the whole thing to make it less tedious.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is increment 'h' depending on which variable has the highest value.
The thing is, when 2 variables have the same value (e.g. B and D are both 7) the code doesn't work at all.

I hope you understood what I'm trying to say and thanks for your time!

Comment: *This is just a template of my actual code, **just so it looks a little more readable**.* I don't envy you if your code is more unreadable than this. This could be QuickBasic. OOP anyone ? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should re-structure your code to make it more readable, and eliminate repetition. But first you need to decide on the order of precedence of your variables when more than one of them has the highest value.

Here is the sketch of how to modify your code:

```
// You may want to make a dedicated method for this
int max = Math.max(Math.max(A, B), Math.max(C, D));
int additional;
if (max == A) {
    additional = 2;
} else if (max == B) {
    additional = 3;
} else if (max == C) {
    additional = 1;
} else if (max == D) {
    additional = 2;
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
while (h < max + additional) {
    r.up();
    h++;
}
```

The idea is to compute the end value using the conditionals, but do the increments in a single loop. The result is a cleaner code without repeated loop.

Comment: This looks like a nice way to restructure my code, but you're forgetting the fact that I also have another variable (E). Math.max only takes 2 arguments so how would I compare all five variables against each other using this same method?

Comment: @antonlab Add another level of `Math.max`, and another `else if(...)` to the above code. You can continue doing this when you expand your code beyond five variables, too.

Comment: Is it necessary to add in `throw new IllegalStateException();`? And if so, why?

Comment: @antonlab Strictly speaking, it is not necessary, if you add initialization to `int additional = 0;` I added it as a self-checking code, in case someone who maintains your code would change the computation of the `max` and forget to update the `if`/`else if` block below.

Comment: Alright thank you! I'm still very new to programming in general and this is very handy to know. I restructured my code and it's working wonders for me :)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you will want to have every comparison use >= rather than >. This will solve the B = D problem.

Edit: You may want to refactor your code. There is a lot of duplicate operations.

Answer (score 0):

Reformulating it as

```
       int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
       if (B > A && B >= C && B > D && B> E )
       {
          max = B + 2;
       }
       else if (D > A && D > B && D >= C && D > E )
       {
          max = D + 3;
       }
       else if (C > A && C > B && C > D && C >= E )
       {
          max = C + 3;
       }

       if (max != Integer.MIN_VALUE)
       {
          while (h < max)
          {
             r.up();
             h++;
          }
       }
```

One sees that A, B, D, E, (C-1) are more or less equivalent, and one wants to take the maximal value of B, C-1, D plus 2 or 3.

Maybe the logic can be further reduced.